# Pick the specific file in the folder in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

I want pick the specific format of file among the list of files in a directory. Please find the below example.

I have a below list of files (6 files).

Set-1 1) MAG_L_NT_AA_SUM_2017_01_20.dat 2) MAG_L_NT_AA_2017_01_20.dat

Set-2 1) MAG_L_NT_BB_SUM_2017_01_20.dat 2) MAG_L_NT_BB_2017_01_20.dat

Set-3 1) MAG_L_NT_CC_SUM_2017_01_20.dat 2) MAG_L_NT_CC_2017_01_20.dat

From the above three sets I need only 3 files. 1) MAG_L_NT_AA_2017_01_20.dat 2) MAG_L_NT_BB_2017_01_20.dat 3) MAG_L_NT_CC_2017_01_20.dat

Note: There can be multiple lines of commands because i have create the script for above req. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need type `find . -regex 'MAG_L_NT_\w\w_2017_01_20.dat'` in shell